# See what sp_execute is doing

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In my MS SQL Profiler i'm seeing lots of these small queries.

> exec sp_execute 1,@p0=15954

I know this works, in theory, that this is executing a previously created query and passing in a specific parameter. But the problem is that i am not sure about what causes these queries.

Is there a way to see the TSQL contents of these queries?

Comment: What events are you currently capturing? If you are using a template for your trace, which template and have you modified the events or columns?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This looks like it's running a prepared query.  One thing to do would be to look through the profiler trace to see if you can find the sp_prepare queries that generating this particular handle.

The other option, would be query system views to find the underlying text.

This will give you the query if it's currently running

```
select text
    from sys.dm_exec_requests
    cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle)
    where session_id = <SPID FROM PROFILER>
```

Comment: By editing the properties of the trace i was able to see the sp_prepare statements and this helped me a lot.

Comment: I used SQL Server Profiler too.  For me, I checked SP:StmtStarting under the 'Stored Procedure' section of the Trace Properties, then ran the trace and I could see the TSQL underneath the frequent sp_execute calls.

Answer (score 19):

In Sql profiler I use Event StoredProcedure>>SP:CacheHit. I read about it in [link](http://performancetestersdiary.wordpress.com/2013/07/01/getting-the-sql-from-a-sp_execute-statement-in-microsoft-sql-profiler/).
Capture SQL:StmtCompleted  and RPC:Completed DIDNT catch the parameter of sp_execute

Comment: RPC:Starting and SP:CacheHit are great together, as you will get the params passed in and the params declared nicely in CacheHit with the main query. Like it!

Comment: You may need to Check the Show All Events Check box